# How to modify a universal adapter tip?

Tags: laptop, power, adapter, tablet

There are two devices (Dell Latitude laptop and Acer Iconia A100 tablet) I have for which I wish I had a single power adapter (for travelling), so I purchased a universal adapter that met the proper power requirements and had the same size tips.

[I bought this adapter](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B012NQ4KPY/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza).
It works fine in the laptop, but not quite right in the Acer Iconia A100 (yes, I know it's old).

When I plug it into the tablet, the power icon does not indicate the presence of the adapter except for a split second when I am pushing in the tip or taking it out.  For a split second it registers.  Th tip fits snugly just like you would hope.  The tip size is correct.

I know the power requirements are correct.  The problem is with the tip.
How can I modify the tip to work?

The Android cable tip reports to be 3.0x1.1mm; the adapter's tip reports to be 3.0x1.0mm.

One thing I notice about the tips is that the original android adapter had a little band etched in it about halfway down the tip, whereas the universal adapter's tip has the band etched right near the end of the tip.  When I push or pull the UA's tip into the Android, however, the flash of power indication doesn't happen at the band (but it doesn't work that way on the original adapter's tip, either).

The original adapter flashes the charging indication as soon as (it seems to me) there is enough length in the tip for the pin to be reached.

Comment: idk either device, but how certain are you that the connectors are identical? It's really difficult to tell by eye between a 2.3mm & 2.5mm for instance; you can force a 2.3 to fit a 2.5 connection with a quick ream of a screwdriver blade & it will still fit a 2.3 [just]. The other way never works. That kit doesn't appear to have a 2.3.

Comment: A universal adapter tip that needs to be adapted to fit something doesn't sound very universal.

Comment: As suggested, you’re using the wrong tip. You said “the tip size is correct.” But you didn’t really provide any information for someone to corroborate that. Exactly what tip did you use?

Comment: I know I have the wrong tip; I was hoping somebody knew how to modify it to work; maybe someone's done it before; the only thing I can think of to do is maybe etch a little band into the tip for the stop area.

Comment: You still didn't tell us what the sizes are, so this is still guesswork... OK, at your own risk, you can make a 2.3 socket fit a 2.5 plug by *gently* bending the middle pin of the socket towards the outer spring clip. It's not as reliable as reaming a 2.3 to fit a 2.5 but it kind of works if you don't break it in the attempt.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'd rather adjust the tip than the socket; any idea there?

Comment: I give up - twice I've asked you which tip & you still didn't answer.. & no, nothing you can do about an oversized tip, except blob solder in it & ream back to correct size; not recommended at all.

Comment: ahh... just saw the edit. No, there's nothing you're going to do with one that small.